# Lottery Unit test (""before each" hook for "can only be called after performUpKeep"')

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, solidity, chai

I am getting this error while running the tests on my Lottery (raffle) from freeCodeCamp 32 hour course.
Yesterday I was able to run each and every test. Then I pushed the code to GitHub and now I am unable to run any test. The error is as following:

```
  Lottery Unit Tests
    fulfillRandomWords      1) "before each" hook for "can only be called after performUpKeep"


  0 passing (869ms)
  1 failing

  1) Lottery Unit Tests       "before each" hook for "can only be called after performUpKeep":
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'call')       at Contract.<anonymous> (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\src.ts\index.ts:397:47)      at step (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:48:23)      at Object.next (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:29:53)      at fulfilled (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:20:58)      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)  
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

this is my testing code which I am writing. Mostly i thing the problem is with that I used both npm and yarn while building this projects due to previous errors.

```
const { assert, expect } = require("chai");
const { network, deployments, ethers, getNamedAccounts } = require("hardhat");
const {
  developmentChains,
  networkConfig,
} = require("../../hardhat-helper-config");

!developmentChains.includes(network.name)
  ? describe.skip
  : describe("Lottery Unit Tests", function() {
      let lottery,
        lotteryContract,
        vrfCoordinatorV2Mock,
        lotteryEntranceFee,
        interval,
        player,
        deployer;

      const chainId = network.config.chainId;

      beforeEach(async () => {
        deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer;
        await deployments.fixture(["all"]);
        lottery = await ethers.getContract("Lottery", deployer);
        vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract(
          "VRFCoordinatorV2Mock",
          deployer
        );
        lotteryContract = await ethers.getContract("Lottery");
        lottery = lotteryContract.connect(player);
        lotteryEntranceFee = await lottery.getEntranceFee();
        interval = await lottery.getInterval();
      });

      // Test for constructor. Similarly, we are going to write test for every function or most imp functions in our contract
      describe("constructor", function() {
        it("initialized the lottery correctly", async function() {
          const lotteryState = await lottery.getLotteryState();
          const interval = await lottery.getInterval();
          assert.equal(lotteryState.toString(), "0");
          assert.equal(
            interval.toString(),
            networkConfig[chainId]["keepersUpdateInterval"]
          );
        });
      });

      // Test for entering into the lottery
      describe("Enter into lottery", function() {
        it("reverts when you don't pay enough", async function() {
          await expect(lottery.enter()).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(
            lottery,
            "NotEnoughETH"
          );
        });
        it("records player when they enter", async function() {
          await lottery.enter({ value: lotteryEntranceFee }); // Enter into lottery by paying entrance fees
          const playerFromContract = await lottery.getPlayer(0);
          assert.equal(playerFromContract, deployer);
        });
        it("emits event on enter", async function() {
          await expect(lottery.enter({ value: lotteryEntranceFee })).to.emit(
            lottery,
            "LotteryEnter"
          );
        });
        it("doesn't allow entrance when lottery is calculating", async function() {
          await lottery.enter({ value: lotteryEntranceFee });
          // Now to get the lottery into calculating state, we need the checkUpKeep to return true and call performUpKeep
          // passing the time of interval in an instance - Time Travel!
          await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [
            interval.toNumber() + 1,
          ]);
          // Mine a block
          await network.provider.request({ method: "evm_mine", params: [] }); // here checkUpkeep returns true
          // Now , we pretned to be a chainlink keeper
          await lottery.performUpkeep([]);
          await expect(
            lottery.enter({ value: lotteryEntranceFee })
          ).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(lottery, "NotOpen");
        });
      });
      describe("checkUpKeep", function() {
        it("returns false if any one is not in the lottery", async function() {
          await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [
            interval.toNumber() + 1,
          ]);
          await network.provider.request({ method: "evm_mine", params: [] });
          // checkUpKeep is a public function which does a transaction
          // When we want to simulate a transaction but don't want to make one
          const { upkeepNeeded } = await lottery.callStatic.checkUpkeep([]); // upkeepNeeded = (timePassed && isOpen && hasBalance && hasPlayers)
          assert(!upkeepNeeded);
        });
        it("returns false if lottery isn't open", async function() {
          await lottery.enter({ value: lotteryEntranceFee });
          await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [
            interval.toNumber() + 1,
          ]);
          await network.provider.request({ method: "evm_mine", params: [] });
          await lottery.performUpkeep([]); // changes the state to calculating
          const lotteryState = lottery.getLotteryState();
          const { upkeepNeeded } = await lottery.callStatic.checkUpkeep([]);
          assert(lotteryState.toString(), "1");
          assert(!upkeepNeeded);
        });
        it("returns false if enough time hasn't passed", async () => {
          await lottery.enter({ value: lotteryEntranceFee });
          await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [
            interval.toNumber() - 5,
          ]); // use a higher number here if this test fails
          await network.provider.request({ method: "evm_mine", params: [] });
          const { upkeepNeeded } = await lottery.callStatic.checkUpkeep([]); // upkeepNeeded = (timePassed && isOpen && hasBalance && hasPlayers)
          assert(!upkeepNeeded);
        });
        it("returns true if enough time has passed, has players, eth, and is open", async () => {
          await lottery.enter({ value: lotteryEntranceFee });
          await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [
            interval.toNumber() + 1,
          ]);
          await network.provider.request({ method: "evm_mine", params: [] });
          const { upkeepNeeded } = await lottery.callStatic.checkUpkeep([]); // upkeepNeeded = (timePassed && isOpen && hasBalance && hasPlayers)
          assert(upkeepNeeded);
        });
      });
      describe("performUpKeep", function() {
        it("It can only run if checkupKeep is true", async function() {
          await lottery.enter({ value: lotteryEntranceFee });
          await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [
            interval.toNumber() + 1,
          ]);
          await network.provider.request({ method: "evm_mine", params: [] });
          const tx = await lottery.performUpkeep([]);
          assert(tx);
        });
        it("reverts when checkupKeep is false", async function() {
          await expect(lottery.performUpkeep([])).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(
            lottery,
            "UpkeepNotNeeded"
          );
        });
        it("updates the lottery state, emits an event, and calls the vrf coordinator", async function() {
          await lottery.enter({ value: lotteryEntranceFee });
          await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [
            interval.toNumber() + 1,
          ]);
          await network.provider.request({ method: "evm_mine", params: [] });
          const txResponse = await lottery.performUpkeep([]);
          const txReceipt = await txResponse.wait(1);
          const lotteryState = lottery.getLotteryState(); // update states
          const requestId = txReceipt.events[1].args.requestId;
          assert(requestId.toNumber() > 0);
          assert(lotteryState, 1); // 0 = open, 1 = calculating
        });
      });
      describe("fulfillRandomWords", function() {
        beforeEach(async () => {
          await lottery.enter({ value: lotteryEntranceFee });
          await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [
            interval.toNumber() + 1,
          ]);
          await network.provider.request({ method: "evm_mine", params: [] });
        });
        it("can only be called after performUpKeep", async () => {
          await expect(
            vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fulfillRandomWords(0, lottery.address) // reverts if not fulfilled
          ).to.be.revertedWith("nonexistent request");
          await expect(
            vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fulfillRandomWords(1, lottery.address) // reverts if not fulfilled
          ).to.be.revertedWith("nonexistent request");
        });

        // This test is too big...
        // This test simulates users entering the raffle and wraps the entire functionality of the raffle
        // inside a promise that will resolve if everything is successful.
        // An event listener for the WinnerPicked is set up
        // Mocks of chainlink keepers and vrf coordinator are used to kickoff this winnerPicked event
        // All the assertions are done once the WinnerPicked event is fired

        it("picks a winner, resets, and sends money", async () => {
          const additionalEntrance = 3;
          const startingAccountIndex = 1; //deployer = 1
          const accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
          for (
            let i = startingAccountIndex;
            i < startingAccountIndex + additionalEntrance;
            i++ // i = 2; i < 5; i=i+1
          ) {
            lottery = lotteryContract.connect(accounts[i]); //Returns a new instance of the Raffle contract connected to player
            await lottery.enter({ value: lotteryEntranceFee });
          }
          const startingTimeStamp = lottery.getLatestTime(); // stores starting timestamp (before we fire our event)

          // performUpKeep (mock being Chainlink Keepers)
          // fulfillRandomWords (mock being the chainlink VRF)
          // We will have to wait for the fulfillRandomWords to be called

          await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            lottery.once("WinnerPicked", async () => {
              console.log("Found the event!");
              try {
                console.log(accounts[0]);
                console.log(accounts[1]);
                console.log(accounts[2]);
                console.log(accounts[3]);
                const recentWinner = await lottery.getRecentWinner();
                const lotteryState = await lottery.getLotteryState();
                const endingTimeStamp = await lottery.getLatestTime();
                const numPlayers = await lottery.getNumOfPlayers();
                console.log(recentWinner);
                assert.equal(numPlayers, 0);
                assert.equal(lotteryState, 0);
                assert(endingTimeStamp > startingTimeStamp);
                resolve(); // if try passes, resolves the promise
              } catch (e) {
                reject(e); // if try fails, rejects the promise
              }
            });
            // Setting up the listener
            // below, we will fire the event, and the listener will pick it up, and resolve
            // kicking off the event by mocking the chainlink keepers and vrf coordinator
            const tx = await lottery.performUpkeep([]);
            const txReceipt = await tx.wait(1);
            await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fulfillRandomWords(
              txReceipt.events[1].args.requestId,
              lottery.address
            );
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

`

Comment: I am having the same issue. Can anybody state what i am seeing this

Answer (score 0):

This is usually seen if the signer object is invalid/undefined. Any activity with an invalid signer object like contract creation, call, send transaction, etc, will have the error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'call')       at Contract. (node_modules@ethersproject\contracts\src.ts\index.ts:397:47)...